# Angular 4 Showing result of adding two numbers in template

Tags: angular

I have following HTML in my template

```
<li class="page-item">
    <a [routerLink]=""
       [queryParams]="{page: currentPage+1}"
       class="page-link" href="#">Next
    </a>
</li>
```

`currentPage` is defined as a `number` in my component

The problem is that the link will show `?page=11` if I click on it when on currentPage 1. If I am on page 2 it shows 21 and so on.

How can I show the result of the addition as a number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function on the page 2 that will convert the String to a Number inside the ts file

```
ConvertToInt(currentPage){
  return parseInt(val);
}
```

then call it

```
<p>{{ ConvertToInt(currentPage) + ConvertToInt(1) }}</p>
```

Comment: Is that because of the JSON even though the currentPage is declared as a number?
Or again something to do with the page? Just curious about the reason.

Comment: @SaiyaffFarouk Since it is being passed as a queryparam, it needs to be converted to as int also when you bind just +1 it will be taken as string.

Comment: Yes, Point: queryParams are parsed as string. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems its treating "currentPage" and "1" both as string, make sure that "currentPage" is really a number or string. In case of no clue try to call a method and get added value from component file. Ex :

```
<li class="page-item"><a [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{page: getPageCount()}" class="page-link" href="#">Next </a> </li>
```